Data types not supported
I need to have the following class
public class BusinessHours {
    private DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;     // Monday, Tuesday, etc.
    private LocalTime startTime;     // When work starts (e.g., 09:00)
    private LocalTime endTime;       // When work ends (e.g., 17:00)
  
   ...
}

However, none of those two data types are supported by JDL. What shall I do?

As a workaround, you can use a Date and refactor with your IDE. Or you could enter an issue in JHipster's issues to request support for these types to be added.

Thanks Matt. I can create a custom enum data type to represent weekdays. On the other hand, it is better to support the LocalTime as it is mapped to the Time in DB with ORM as none of the current JDL data types mapped into Time in DB. I will create an issue ticket later.

I also can place the startTime and endTime into String and parse them in the application.
